# How to start and stop an Amazon EC2 instance programmatically in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How do i start and stop an amazon EC2 instance programmatically using aws-sdk in ruby?

i want to start and stop it automatically without using the AWS OpsWorks.

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Instance.new(region:'ap-southeast-1', credentials:Aws::Credentials.new('AKIAJG2625V5PTS47IGQ',      'dIZnEuRBYBtX8CBjbC0l3JLL//4hB25aE13b7+fP'),id:'i-650400a1')
ec2.stop
```

Comment: did you even try anything? Maybe like reading [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsRuby/latest/DeveloperGuide/run-instance.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Directly from [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsRuby/latest/DeveloperGuide/run-instance.html):

Use the [`InstanceCollection.create`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/InstanceCollection.html#create-instance_method) method to run an Amazon EC2 instance. Specify the Amazon Machine Image (AMI), the instance type, the maximum number of instance to run, the names of a security group and key pair you created, as follows:

```
instance = ec2.instances.create(
:image_id => 'ami-11d68a54',
:instance_type => 'm1.small',
:count => 1, 
:security_groups => 'YOUR_SECURITY_GROUP_NAME', 
:key_pair => ec2.key_pairs['YOUR_KEY_PAIR_NAME'])
```

To stop:

```
instance.stop
```